# Кнопка не делается неактивной android

Tags: android

У меня есть два поля для ввода пароля и логина, и я пытаюсь вставить проверку на заполненность полей, то есть если хотя-бы одно из полей или два одновременно поля пусты, то мы делаем кнопку неактивной и потом делаем фокус на пустое поле. Я нашел такой вариант решения моей проблемы:

```
 final EditText titleEt = findViewById(R.id.login);
        final EditText bodyEt = findViewById(R.id.password);
        final String a = titleEt.getText().toString().trim();
        final String b = bodyEt.getText().toString().trim();
        final Button btn = findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);

if(a.equals("")&&b.equals(""))
                    {
                        btn.setClickable(false);
                    }
                    else {
                        btn.setClickable(true);
                    }
```

но у меня почему-то кнопка все-равно нажимается, хотя по логике не должна. Может я что-то не учел или не где-то есть ошибка? Надеюсь на ваши советы и помощь.

Comment: Вы сравниваете на "если оба поля пусты" (&&), а хотите сравнить на "если хотя бы одно из поле пусто" ( || ).

Comment: та я уже по разному пробовал, мой способ не рабочий, приведенный ниже способ помог, спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лучше сделайте так:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

       if(s.toString().trim().length()==0){
            button.setEnabled(false);
          } else {
            button.setEnabled(true);
          }
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```